# Date/Time formatting in access textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an issue, and believe its simple to resolve but cant work out how.

My table, which has showing both date & time can not be amended because that is how I receive my data.

Ive changed the format in the table design to short date and it shows fine, it hides the time.

I also changed the textbox that displays the date to short date but its still showing both the date and time, why?

Primarily, I have another textbox that I want to calculate the table date + 30, my expression used is:

```
=[text5]+30
```

The textbox is displayed blank.

Any help?

Comment: Why not simply `datevalue(fieldnamehere+30)` rather than all that complication?

Comment: I tried that and get a #TYPE! error

Comment: What is the data type of the field?

Comment: Its set to date/time

Comment: Is the field / column a reserved name? Have you got null values in the field?

Comment: Its called OpenedDate - Every cell has a date in them

Comment: If you type in the immediate window `?datevalue(now()+30)` does it work?

Comment: hmmm, yeah works. Shows todays date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128273/discussion-between-fionnuala-and-david).

Comment: Just realised the excel document it gets copied in from has the cell as a customer format of: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss   - Im guessing this is causing the issue?

Comment: Seems likely, but we have reached the discussion limit for commets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your date field is linked as text. So convert to Date:

```
=DateValue([OpenedDate])
```

and for the +30 date:

```
=DateAdd("d",30,DateValue([OpenedDate]))
```

However, there is no way that:

```
? DateValue(Now() + 30)
```

can show today's date. It will show 30 days ahead of today.